# Upper and Lower Bounds question grade 9

Tags: elementary-number-theory, education

I am a student and And I need help with answering this question. I don't understand how to work out the surface area with just knowing the volume.

Question:

Correct to 2 decimal place, the volume of a solid cube is 3.37m^3.
Calculate the upper bound for the surface area of the cube.

What I have tried:

I have tried to find the upper bound of 3.37 which is 3.375. I don't know what to do next. I know that to find the overall upper bound in division is:  UB/LB

Thank you and help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you work out the edge length when you know the volume? With that, can you calculate the surface area?

Comment: I don't know how to

Comment: Once you find an upper bound, try adding 17 square meters and see if that is not an upper bound as well. It would be a good exercise to write down the question that someone intended to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Hint (following OP's comment).

You know that an upper bound for the edge length $E$ satisfies $E^3 = 3.375$. That's enough information to find $E$ using a calculator. You probably have keys to press for that, but you can do it with guess-and-check if necessary.

Comment: I have worked out the answer:

Comment: You find UB of 3.37:  3.375. and find cube root of 3.375 which is 1.5 and then you work out the surface area which is 13.5m^2. Thankyou